# How can i define a var as object from a object in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a situation that i want to iterate polygons and its name some thing like this

```
 for key in result:
            my_poly.push ( map.drawPolygon({
                paths: key.poly_points,
                title: key.name,
                draggable: true,
                editable: true,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                click: function(e) {
                    alert('You clicked ' + my_poly.title);
                }

           });
        )
```

from the result like this

```
{"poly1":{"name":"a1","poly_points":[[47.5318968167,7.70495563751],
                                      [47.5320376772,7.70489126449],    
                                      [47.5317713226,7.70478934055],                    
                                      [47.5318968167,7.70495563751]]}}
```

If i Iterate the result the key value is poly1 and its string ,but i want it to be a obj to get the values from the inner array of the poly1 like this

```
 key.name=a1,
 key.poly_points= [[47.5318968167,7.70495563751],                       
              [47.5320376772,7.70489126449],    
              [47.5317713226,7.70478934055],                   
              [47.5318968167,7.70495563751]]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Because it probably a json string, you need to json decode it.

Comment: @@Rahil Wazir :How can i do that.? Can you paste me sample of it from my script?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(key.poly_points)`

Comment: @@ Rahil Wazir : JSON.parse(key.poly_points) is not working. i get an SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the current item in the loop use `result[key]`

```
 for (var key in result){
        my_poly.push ( map.drawPolygon({
            paths: result[key].poly_points,
            title: result[key].name,
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            click: function(e) {
                alert('You clicked ' + this.title);
            }

       })
    )}
```

Comment: @@Dr.Molle: I tried like the way you tell, but the problem is icant able to get the correct title/polygon name. I have bunch of polygons and its name

Comment: @@Dr.Molle : i get the title when i click  the polygon on google map

Comment: Then your implementation of the click-handler in drawPolygon is wrong

Comment: @@Dr. Molle: What i get when i click on the polygon is the last name from the list of the polygon name. I dont know y. I m confussed